# How to find index of a given value in a nested list in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, nested-lists, traversal

I wat to traverse over the nested list below, find 1 then print index of that list.

```
my_list = [['Hello', 'World','!'],[1, 3, 'Test', 5, 7],[2, 4]]

for item in range(len(my_list)):
    for item2 in range(len(my_list[item])):
        output = my_list[item][item2]
        if output == 1:
            print('the index of 1 is [%d][%d] ' % (item.item2))
```

The loops above returned `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'item2'`

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Instead of (item.item2) do (item, item2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems fine in your code, just make the string formatter a tuple. Modify the last line of your code to this below:

```
print('the index of 1 is [%d][%d] ' % (item,item2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `enumerate` on the nested list to use both the index of the item in the list and the respective list item.

To find the index of an item use the `list_name.index(value)` method.

Use `in` to check the membership i.e. to check if a value is in the list.

```py
my_list = [['Hello', 'World','!'],[1, 3, 'Test', 5, 7],[2, 4]]

for i, item in enumerate(my_list):
    if 1 in item:
        print('Index of 1 is [{}][{}]'.format(i,item.index(1)))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Not a functional problem, but I think `i1, i2` would be a less confusing naming choice for the loop variables

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in my_list:
    if 1 in i:
        print(str(i.index(1)) + "th element of " + str(i))
```

This outputs

```
0th element of [1, 3, 'Test', 5, 7]
```